# Dispatcher.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python

What am I doing wrong and why am I getting this error?

```python
TOKEN_API = "1"

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, executor

bot = Bot(token="TOKEN_API")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def send_random_letter(message : types.Message):
    await message.answer("hi,print /generate_pictures, to start")
```

I get an error:

```
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Dispatcher.__init__() takes 1 positional argument, but 2 were given
```

Please help.

I only started and I don't know what to write.

Comment: Please read the [migration FAQ](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/migration_2_to_3.html#dispatcher).

Answer (score 0):

The `Dispatcher.__init__()` you were trying to call was documented [here](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/dispatcher/dispatcher.html).

```py
def __init__(self, *, storage: BaseStorage | None = None, fsm_strategy: FSMStrategy = FSMStrategy.USER_IN_CHAT, events_isolation: BaseEventIsolation | None = None, disable_fsm: bool = False, name: str | None = None, **kwargs: Any)
```

It does not take any positional arguments (you need to specify the options using keyword arguments. The one argument you are seeing is actually the self argument, which refers to the class itself and you do not really need to care about it.

The actual way to do what you was trying to do was also documented at the bottom of the in [Handling Updates](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/dispatcher/dispatcher.html#handling-updates).

```py
bot = Bot(...)
dp = Dispathcher()

...

result = await dp.feed_update(bot=bot, update=incoming_update)
```

Comment: this is my first bot, I honestly don't understand what you're talking about.What am I doing wrong and how to fix my function

Comment: You don't need to call Dispatcher with the bot. You need to update it with the bot with result = await dp.feed_update(bot=bot, update=incoming_update)